# Proof related to $C([a,b],\mathbb{R}^n)=\{ f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^n:f=(f_1\ldots f_n)/f \text{ is continuous on }[a,b]\}$ where $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

### Question

Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$,

We define the set $C([a,b], \mathbb{R}^n) = \{ f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n:f=(f_1\ldots f_n)/f \text{ is continuous on } [a,b]\}$

Prove that $C([a,b], \mathbb{R}^n)$ forms a linear space in relation to the estimation operations of two functions in $C([a,b], \mathbb{R}^n)$, respectively of multiplication with real scalars with functions from $C([a,b], \mathbb{R}^n)$.

### My Attempt

I know that we have to prove the $10$ axioms of vector spaces, I just don't know how to take the functions, I mean in what form to take them, so that I can prove those axioms in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Please, I just need a hint on how to take those two functions $f$ and $g$ in what form to prove those $10$ axioms.

Comment: It will generally amount to the fact that sums of continuous functions are continuous, and scalar multiples of continuous functions are also continuous. Most of the other stuff will reduce to fairly low-level properties of arithmetic (e.g. because addition of real numbers is associative, addition in this function space is also associative). Which isn't to say it shouldn't be written down to demonstrate that you understand what you're checking. I'm just saying, there's really nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Please check the edit post! I know that those axioms most of them are trivial that's what i am so confused how i should do that, anyway i translate th exercise exactley as i have it, and i think it remain only to prove the addition and the multiplication but still don't know in what form i should use f and g, this is so confusing to me, but thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the axioms are readily verified and don't require much attention, seeing as they are more or less pretty obvious. Perhaps the more sensible ones would be showing that the addition of two continuous functions is again continuous, as well as that any scalar multiple of a continuous function is indeed continuous, so I will prove these for you here.

Let $f, g \in C([a, b], \mathbb{R}^n)$ and $x \in [a, b]$ fixed. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ be fixed (that the function which is identically zero is continuous is immediate). Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x,$ there exist $\delta_\varepsilon^f, \delta_\varepsilon^g > 0$ such that $\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert < \min \{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon}{\vert \lambda \vert} \} > \Vert g(x) - g(y) \Vert$ whenever $\vert x - y \vert < \delta_\varepsilon^f$ and $\vert x - y \vert < \delta_\varepsilon^g,$ respectively, where I think it's pretty clear how they correspond to each other ($\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes the standard euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$). It follows that for all $y \in [a, b]$ with $\vert x - y \vert < \min \{\delta_\varepsilon^f, \delta_\varepsilon^g\},$ we have that $$\Vert f(x) + g(x) - f(y) - g(y) \Vert \leq \Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert + \Vert g(x) - g(y) \Vert \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$ and $$\Vert \lambda f(x) - \lambda f(y) \Vert = \vert \lambda \vert \Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert \leq \vert \lambda \vert \frac{\varepsilon}{\vert \lambda \vert} = \varepsilon,$$ which proves continuity of $f + g$ and $\lambda f.$

Comment: Thank you so much, God bless you!

Comment: It's my pleasure! :)